# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist domain object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to Spring and I've been using [this](http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) tutorial to help me build `@ManyToMany` relationships. I'm trying to make a ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Role` and then another ManyToMany relationship between `Role` and `Permission`. I've followed the article throughout and I seem to be getting this error and cannot figure out why it's happening.

Note: I am using Gradle, not Maven; I don't know if that makes any difference. I am also using perisistence with `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`.

## Stacktrace

```
2016-06-23 11:35:17.312 ERROR 7389 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:701)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:688)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:678)
Exception in thread "main"  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:971)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:960)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.main(AdeyTrackApplication.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.save(Unknown Source)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.createRoleIfNotFound(AdeyTrackApplication.java:112)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.run(AdeyTrackApplication.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:698)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:452)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:409)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:701)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:688)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:678)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:971)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:960)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.main(AdeyTrackApplication.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.save(Unknown Source)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.createRoleIfNotFound(AdeyTrackApplication.java:112)
    at AdeyTrack.AdeyTrackApplication.run(AdeyTrackApplication.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    ... 7 more  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:452)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:409)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 17 more
```

ApplicationRunner:

```java
package AdeyTrack;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import AdeyTrack.domain.Role;
import AdeyTrack.domain.Permissions;
import AdeyTrack.domain.User;
import AdeyTrack.persistence.repository.PermissionsRepository;
import AdeyTrack.persistence.repository.RoleRepository;
import AdeyTrack.persistence.repository.UserRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AdeyTrackApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    boolean setup = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdeyTrackApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    private PermissionsRepository permRepo;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepo;


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        if(setup){ return ; }

        /* Create permissions */        
        Permissions edit_store = createPermissionsIfNotFound(Permission.STORE.PERM_STORE_EDIT.name(), "edit a store");
        Permissions create_store = createPermissionsIfNotFound(Permission.STORE.PERM_STORE_CREATE.name(), "create a store");

        List<Permissions> adminPermissions = Arrays.asList(edit_store, create_store);

        /* Create roles */

        createRoleIfNotFound("STORE_ADMIN", adminPermissions);
        createRoleIfNotFound("STORE_EDITOR", Arrays.asList(create_store));

        Role adminRole = roleRepo.findByRole("STORE_ADMIN");
        Role editRole = roleRepo.findByRole("STORE_EDITOR");

        User storeadmin = new User("storeadmin", pe.encode("password"));
        User storeedit  = new User("storeedit", pe.encode("password"));


        storeadmin.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));
        storeedit.setRoles(Arrays.asList(editRole));

        userRepo.save(storeadmin);
//      userRepo.save(storeedit);

        setup = true;

    }

    @Transactional
    private Permissions createPermissionsIfNotFound(String name, String description){
        Permissions permission = permRepo.findByPermission(name);
        if(permission == null){
            permission = new Permissions(name, description);
            permRepo.save(permission);
        }
        return permission;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Role createRoleIfNotFound(String name, Collection<Permissions> permissions) {
        Role role = roleRepo.findByRole(name);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new Role(name);
            role.setPermissions(permissions);
            roleRepo.save(role);
        }
        return role;
    }

}
```

User.java

```java
package AdeyTrack.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="users_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(){
        super();
    }

    public User(String login, String password){
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> role) {
        this.roles = role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }   

}
```

Role.java

```java
package AdeyTrack.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;


import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="role_permissions",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Collection<Permissions> rolePermissions;

    public Role(){
        super();
    }

    public Role(String role){
        super();
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Role(String role, Collection<Permissions> permissions){
        super();
        this.role = role;
        this.rolePermissions = permissions;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users){
        if(users.size() == 1){
            this.users = users;
        } else if(users.size() > 1){
            this.users.addAll(users);
        }
    }

    public Collection<User> getUsers(){
        return users;
    }

    public void setPermissions(Collection<Permissions> permissions){
        this.rolePermissions = permissions;
    }

    public Collection<Permissions> getPermissions(){
        return rolePermissions;
    }

}
```

Permission.java

```java
package AdeyTrack.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="permissions")
public class Permissions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rolePermissions", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    private String permission;
    private String description;

    public Permissions(){
        super();
    }

    public Permissions(String permission, String description){
        super();
        this.permission = permission;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRole() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRole(Collection<Role> role) {
        this.roles = role;
    }

    public String getPermission(){
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(String permission){
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using @Transactional, many important aspects such as transaction propagation are handled automatically. In this case if another transactional method is called by `businessLogic()`, that method will have the option of joining the ongoing transaction.

```
@Transactional
public void businessLogic() {
    ... use entity manager inside a transaction ...
}
```

One potential downside is that this powerful mechanism hides what is going on under the hood, making it hard to debug when things don't work.

One of the key points about `@Transactional` is that there are two separate concepts to consider, each with it's own scope and life cycle:

> ```
> the persistence context
> the database transaction
> ```

The transactional annotation itself defines the scope of a single database transaction. The database transaction happens inside the scope of a persistence context.

The persistence context is in **JPA** the **EntityManager**, implemented internally using an Hibernate **Session** (when using Hibernate as the persistence provider).

The persistence context is just a synchronizer object that tracks the state of a limited set of Java objects and makes sure that changes on those objects are eventually persisted back into the database.

This is a very different notion than the one of a database transaction. One Entity Manager can be *used across several database transactions*, and it actually often is.

Comment: Right I see. I was mainly getting confused on the EntityManager notion as most people seem to use that to see if an Object already exists and if it can be _merged_ or if there's a beed to _create_ it again. Would it be important to use `@Transactional` in the controllers of the application where we are persisting and manipulating data on user requests?

Comment: in the controller you will autowire your services..which are using @Transactional , so no need to use it

Comment: So usually where I would autowire my repositories to use with the controller scope, I should autowire also my UserDetailsService etc? Sorry for the noob responses, I'm just trying to get my head around how the beans and hibernate work hand-in-hand.

Comment: i think this example will help you to understand how its working.
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

So I feel extremely stupid because the whole issue lies in the Application runner. After doing a little bit more digging around I discovered that it is vital to use `@Transactional` in the `run` method, I have no clue why this is the case but just adding that annotation has fixed everything for some reason.